# delete test data in laravel migration script

Tags: laravel, laravel-seeding

I am trying to clean the test data from my production tables. In simple environment I can write a script to clean the test data but I wonder how can I do the same in laravel migration script

I have a test user on production and want to clean all related records generated in the database.In a seed file I can fetch student id based on email address and then remove courses and other info based on the id?. I don't know if it sounds like a laravel way of doing things!

studentId = 101

He is enrolled to three courses
He has attendance records
He has communication records

Now I want to fetch student id based on his emailId
then want to delete records from courses, attendance, communication table
and finally delete id from student table

I am doing

```
$sdetail = student::where('email','some@test.com')->first();
echo "you are checking fir: ".$sdetail ->id;
$classes= class::where('studentId',"$sdetail->id")->get();
foreach($classes as $class)
{
    echo $class->name;   //print only one record I have three rec!
    DB::table('courses')->where("id",$class->id)->delete();
}
```

any idea fix this!

Comment: Solution is to write DB::Raw(db queries).. to write your test data cleaning script

Answer (score 7):

You can run model functions within a migration - you just need to include the model at the top.

```
use App\ModelName

class RemoveTestData extends Migration {

    public function up(){

        ModelName::where('id', $ID)->first()->delete();

    }

    public function down(){

        ModelName::create([
            //Test Data
        ]);

    }
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

use App\Models\settings;

class ChangeCreateSettingsInsert extends Migration
{
  public function up()
  {
    settings::create([
        "product_id" => 1           
    ]);
  }

  public function down()
  {
    settings::where('product_id',1)->delete();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `truncate()` function in a migration to remove all rows and reset any auto increment fields.

```
Schema::table('table_name', function($table)
{
    $table->truncate();
});
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#deletes

Comment: I want to only delete test data recordset not whole table in my production env.

Comment: Apologies for misunderstanding. Do you have a model set up for the table you wish to modify?

Comment: Yes model classes are defined for all tables

Answer (score 1):

I just bumped into the same exact issue today and I find  another way to do it when you hydrate your database:

// Include the model in your file
use App\Models\ModelName;

```
public function down()
{
    ModelName::query()->delete();

}
```

the query() makes the connection with you DB and allows you to delete your datas

I hope this helps as well :)